# How do I hide the hide Recycle Bin from the desktop in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, recycle-bin

I prefer it when there aren't any items on the desktop. Is there a way to hide the Recycle Bin in Windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the Start  button, then select Settings .
Select Personalization > Themes > Desktop icon settings.
Uncheck the Recycle Bin check box > Apply.

Source https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/15057/windows-show-hide-recycle-bin